# Defer inline jQuery Ready/Bind functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some legacy jQuery executing in the page that can't be moved i.e.

```
jQuery(document).bind('click', function(){
    console.log('click');
});
```

Now that loading of jQuery is at the bottom of the page 'AFTER' the above inline code, the page errors 'jQuery is undefined'

I would like to use a pattern similar to this:

```
var deferInlineScripts = []; 
    window.$ = function(inlineFunction) {
    deferInlineScripts.push(inlineFunction);
};
```

Seen working here: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/165864/

that takes the inline scripts and executes them (Once jQuery is loaded') using

```
for (i = 0; i < deferInlineScripts.length; i++) {
    deferInlineScripts[i]();
}
```

But unlike the Fiddle my legacy code doesn't have the $(function(){}); and can't be moved, changed or have anything wrapped around it i.e

```
jQuery(document).bind('click', function(){
    console.log('click');
});
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('ready');
});
```

Here is the Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/165972/ that I would like to fix so the the Bind & Ready functions execute after jQuery is loaded.

Comment: The pattern you're following is not quite right. You're creating a fuzzy function for `jQuery` which queues whatever is passed to it as a parameter. But in reality, `document` is what being passed to it, and not the `bind` or `ready` function. So it queues `document` in the array, and of course, it is not a function, as pointed out by the console error in your fiddle.

Comment: Yes I understand that the function(inlineFunction){deferInlineScripts.push(inlineFunction);}; is incorrect, that is the function that needs to be rewritten unfortunately my JS skills are not up to the complexity

Answer (score 0):

Initially define `window.jQuery` as a function that returns a Proxy. This proxy will allow subsequent *arbitrary* psuedo-propery lookups (such as `.bind` in `jQuery(document).bind`) to be performed. The properties accessed and the arguments the resulting function is eventually called with can be stored in an array and then executed once jQuery is properly loaded.

```html
<script>
const deferCallHandler = {
  get: function(jqFirstArg, jqProp) {
    return function(...secondArgs) {
      deferredInlineScripts.push({
        jqFirstArg,
        jqProp,
        secondArgs,
      });
    }
  }
};
const deferredInlineScripts = [];
window.jQuery = function(jqFirstArg) {
  return new Proxy(jqFirstArg, deferCallHandler);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  // window.jQuery has now been properly assigned to the true jQuery object
  deferredInlineScripts.forEach(({ jqFirstArg, jqProp, secondArgs }) => {
    jQuery(jqFirstArg)[jqProp](...secondArgs);
  });
});

/* Can't change this code */
jQuery(document).bind('click', function(){
  console.log('click');
});
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  console.log('ready');
});

</script>
<div>some element</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```